# Who introduced the heart ($\mathcal{C}^\heartsuit$) notation in the context of $t$-structures on triangulated categories?

Tags: ho.history-overview, notation, triangulated-categories, perverse-sheaves, t-structure

In the context of $t$-structures
([[Wikipedia]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T-structure),
[[nLab]](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/t-structure),
[[Notes I]](https://www.ihes.fr/%7E/gabber/t-str.pdf),
[[Notes II]](http://math.mit.edu/%7Esidnv/Introduction_to_Perverse_Sheaves.pdf),
[[HA, Definition 1.2.1.11)]](http://people.math.harvard.edu/%7Elurie/papers/HA.pdf),
[[BBD, Définition 1.3.1]](https://publications.ias.edu/sites/default/files/Faisceaux%20pervers.pdf)),
one often writes $\mathcal{C}^\heartsuit$ for the heart of a category $\mathcal{C}$ equipped with a $t$-structure $(\mathcal{C}_{\leq0},\mathcal{C}_{\geq0})$.

While I've seen this notation used in many modern references, such as [[HA, Definition 1.2.1.11]](http://people.math.harvard.edu/%7Elurie/papers/HA.pdf), it seems it was not introduced together with the notion of heart in [[BBD, Définition 1.3.1]](https://publications.ias.edu/sites/default/files/Faisceaux%20pervers.pdf), at least in print.

Where did this notation first appear? Was it already commonplace in handwritten sources or chalk talks at the time of [[BBD]](https://publications.ias.edu/sites/default/files/Faisceaux%20pervers.pdf)?